# How to make list similar to Android Contact list in xaml?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8.1

I am trying to figure out a way to create a list similar to
 [image] 
for a windows 8.1 app. Is there a nuget package for such list control or do I have to create my own. So far I am able to create search input and list of names, but I am not sure how to handle alphabetical buttons and to make the list scroll to specific group of contact.

Comment: It's a really broad question, but [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh780627.aspx) will get you started. It's probably not as tough as you think. Cheers.

Comment: Looks like an `ItemsControl` with grouping next to a vertical `StackPanel`.  The `ItemTemplate` just looks like a 3 column `Grid` with an `Image` a `TextBlock`, and another `Image`.

Comment: @ChrisW. There is no CollectionViewSource in Windows 8.1 controls. Can you suggest any alternative control?

Comment: @BradleyUffner I can build the layout, my question is regarding grouping and scroll to specific group when you click and alphabat button.

Comment: That should just be a matter of binding the fields correctly and setting properties in your view model.  For example, bind the `ItemsControl` to `Contacts` on your VM, when the user clicks "a" set the VM's `SelectedContact` to the first Item in the `Contacts` list that starts with "A".  The bindings will take care of scrolling it in to view and selecting it visually.

Comment: I just noticed that you found there is no `CollectionViewSource` in Windows 8.1, that is going to make this significantly more difficult.  Unfortunately I don't know of an easy work around, as I primarily work in WPF.

Comment: Ah ok ya sorry about that, wasn't paying attention I guess. Like Bradley pointed out, that does make things more interesting. Will have to circle back to this when time allows to actually think about it.

Comment: CollectionViewSource worked, thank you @BradleyUffner